# Good reference on the parametrization of SU(3) and SU(N)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation

For the 2-dimensional $SU(2)$ matrices, there is a fairly general parametrization formulation:

$s_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    e^{i\alpha}cos(\theta) & -e^{-i\beta}sin(\theta) \\
    e^{i\beta}sin(\theta) & e^{-i\alpha}cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$

For the 3-dimension SU(3) and the higher-dimension SU(N) matrices, what are the most general parametrization formulations? I will appreciate any references, either a book or a review paper, on this subject oriented toward the physics/engineer applications.

Comment: For compact connected Lie groups the exponential map from the Lie algebra is surjective, although it's not bijective. This is usually good enough for various applications.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! Could you please point me to some good review/tutorial references? It would be even better if it is written for the broader audiences rather than the pure mathematicians.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what sort of answer you're looking for. One version of the answer is: every matrix in $SU(N)$ has the form $\exp X$ where $X$ is an $N \times N$ matrix with complex entries such that 1) $X^{\dagger} = -X$, where $X^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose, and 2) $\text{tr}(X) = 0$. Is that explicit enough for you? What are you planning on using a parameterization of $SU(N)$ to do?

Comment: I guess I am looking for a general parametrization of the $\boldsymbol X$. So it would be easier to manipulate, as well as to understand, in the numerical computations. For example, in the case of $SU(2)$ given in the question, the $\theta$ parameterizes the different orthonormal coefficients while the $\alpha$ and the $\beta$ phases. Hope this clarifies my question a bit.